# How can I typeset the abstract grade school algorithm for multiplication?

Tags: formatting

I'd like to get something looking like this

[image: Abstract Multiplication]

Note that I don't want to typeset a concrete example. I want something as close to the given picture as possible. In particular I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the box-plot-like whiskers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[|-|] (5,0) -- ++(6,0) node[midway,fill=white]{$m$ bits};
 \draw[|-|] (5,-0.5) node[left]{$\times$} -- ++(6,0) node[midway,fill=white]{$n$ bits};
 \draw[-] (3.5,-1) -- ++(9,0);
 \draw (4,-1.5) -- ++(6,0) coordinate (tr) -- ++(-2,-4) coordinate (br) 
 --++(-6,0) coordinate (bl) -- cycle;
 \draw[-] (0,-6) -- ++(9,0);
 \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3mm}] (tr)  --  (br -| tr)
 node[midway,right=5mm]{$n$ rows};
 \coordinate (low) at (0,-6.5);
 \draw[|-|] (low -| bl) -- (low -| tr)node[midway,fill=white]{$n+m$ bits};
 \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4mm}] (low -| tr) -- (low -| bl)
 node[midway,below=5mm]{$n+m$ columns};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to have these whiskers in formulas somehow?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff You can o both: include this or another Ti*k*Z picture in formulas or use Ti*k*Z to annotate formulas with the `overlay` option. This site is full of examples, one way to find them is to do a Google picture search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com` and some appropriate keywords.